# How to set and use same variable in single line in a windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I tried below procedure but unable to succeed set and use same value in another expression

```
set a=10 & echo %a%
```

unable to achieve from above mentioned cmd ;do we have any other alternative to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion & set "a=10" & echo !a! & endlocal
```

or

```
 set "a=10" & call echo %%a%%
```

Answer (score -4):

In a batch file:

```
@echo off
(set A=10) & echo %A%
```

It is important to use parenthesis around `set` so it is known where content of variable is terminated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why is my solution so bad, that it got so down-voted?